# How to implement conditional probability distribution on set-valued Random variables?

Tags: probability, distributions, conditional-probability, probabilistic-programming, set-theory

A Random Set is a set-valued RV, i.e. a map $X:\Omega\to\mathcal{C}$ from a probability space $(\Omega,\Lambda,P)$ to the family of measurable closed sets $\mathcal{C}$ on a $\sigma-$algebra $\Lambda$ built from the elementals $\omega\in\Omega$ (with $\Omega$ countable), and such RV takes set values:

$$X^{-1}(K)=\{ \omega|X(\omega)\cap K\neq\emptyset \},$$

where $K$ is a closet set called the "trap" or structuring set. For simplicity, I denoted $X^{-1}(K)\in\mathcal{X}$ by $x_i$, and $Y^{-1}(K)\in\mathcal{Y}$ by $y_j$, and $X(\omega)$ by $X$.

I'm trying to implement conditional probability distribution $Y|X$. So, for $Y=y_j$, given $X=x_i$, we can use the Bayes theorem:
$$P(Y=y_j|X=x_i)=\frac{P(X=x_i|Y=y_j)P(Y=y_j)}{\sum_{y_j'\in\mathcal{Y}}P(X=x_i|Y=y_j')P(Y=y_j')}=\frac{f(x_i,y_j)}{\sum_{y_j'\in\mathcal{Y}}f(x_i,y_j')},$$
where the question is, how to define $f(x_i,y_j)$ as $X,Y$ take values on the sets of sets $\mathcal{X}=\{x_1,\dots,x_\ell\}$ and $\mathcal{Y}=\{y_1,\dots,y_{\ell'} \}$, respectively?

I've tried with this:
$$(1)\hspace{10mm}f(x_i,y_j)=\sum_{(x_i',y_j')} |x_i\cap x_i' |\cdot|y_j\cap y_j'|. $$

However, I'm not sure how to verify here the usual notion of quatifying the observation of the outcome $(x_i,y_j)$ over the set of outcomes $\{ (x_i', y_j')\} $. Please, someone can help me to get the right expression for Eq. (1)?

Comment: The usual formulae hold in this case. "$X=x$" means "$X$ is the set $x$". Two sets either are the same set or are distinct, so the assertions "$X=x'$" and "$X=x''$" are contradictory if $x'$ and $x''$ aren't the same set. This means that your initial (inline) formula for $f(x,y)$ *formally* holds. This is an uncontable sample space, so the sum should be replaced by an integral (a gauge integral rather than Lebegue), but the reasoning proceeds as for any other continuous sample space. You are maybe misleading yourself by writing "$X_i$" for a specific value rather than "$x_i$".

Comment: Actually the sum for $f(x,y)$ is correct if your sample space (which is a set of sets) contains a finite number of sets.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @pglpm. So, it suffices with mentioning that I'm talking about sets, instead of denoting them in this scenario? Or what is the best way to denote them?

Comment: It depends. It isn't clear to me what you mean with "events drawn by $X$, $Y$ are sets". Do you mean for example that the values that $X$ can take are sets? Or do you mean that you are considering several values of $X$? For example, if $X$ takes on values in the set $\{1,2,3\}$, then writing "$X = \{1,2\}$" would be nonsense. If $X$ takes on values in a set of sets, for example $\bigl\{\{1,2\},\ \{1,3\},\ \{4,5\}\bigr\}$, then "$X=\{1,2\}$" does make sense – it's one of the possible "values" (sets) that $X$ can have.

Comment: Also the sentence "$X_i \cap Y_j$ provides a measure of how the attributes of both sets should be observed jointly" is very unclear. What is the "attribute" of a set? What does "observing an attribute" mean? I'm not sure whether you are a bit hurried in writing and so the sentences didn't come out right, or whether you may have some misunderstanding or confusion about the notions of random variable, event, sample space, and so on...

Comment: You say *events are sets*, you probably wants to say that *outcomes are sets*. Maybe tell us about the concrete background for your Q?

Comment: Dear @pglpm, thanks a lot for helping me to fix the terminology. Indeed, I wanted to mean that $X$ takes values on a set of sets, so what is the best way you suggest to denote such values? Now, by saying "attributes" I tried to be simple. However what I wanted to say that each value of the RV is built by elementary objects $\omega\in\Omega$ such that some $\sigma-$algebra is generated by a power set $2^\Omega$, and some topology takes place by means of finite unions. The RVs are elements of a family of closed and measurable sets, so a measure $\mu$ is present.

Comment: Dear @kjetil b halvorsen. I'm trying to understand this kind of methods and their theoretical guarantees https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.00451 (set-valued classifiers) and implement them by my own. Do you have some ideas to clarify this?

Comment: No problem, I didn't help very much. Curious paper the one you mention. Personally I don't see the logic of forming and outputting sets of possible values for a classification, if I can have a probability distribution over the possible values instead. It's more informative and can thereafter be used within decision theory to make a choice. Sets of possible values cannot be used that way...
From this (personal) point of view a set of sets is not needed. Good old probability over the original set is all one needs.

Comment: You are studying [*random sets*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_compact_set)

Comment: @pglpm I only found interesting the problem of predicting sets instead of points, although the paper point out some undesirable properties also (you are right in that the paper makes it appear that there is no difference in applying set-valued classifiers and usual ones).

Comment: @kjetil b halvorsen , you are right and at this moment I have been seen theoretical background (Random Sets, Set-Valued Analysis). I didn't find how to perform the computations, and most of the literature assumes Hausdorff metric spaces.

Comment: But you seems to have subsets of a finite space (discrete metric space) which certainly is Haussdorf ...

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen, you are certainly right. Nonetheless, I omitted the fact that when $\omega\not\in\mathbb{R}$ strictly we have not a metric space, even when the notion of length is present (although not needed due to the hit-and-miss topology), so we can adapt the Hausdorff metric. In my case, and in the case of the paper I shared, $\omega\in\mathbb{R}$ isn't a requirement ($\Omega$ is only a set of countable objects, as pointed out by @Ben). Please correct me in the case of a mistake.

Comment: I'm starting to understand your question. A set of sets is like any other set, so you can choose any probability distribution (measure) over it that you like. So both (1) and (2) are admissible if they're positive and normalized (I haven't checked). It seems that you want to choose a distribution with some symmetries w.r.t. the intrinsic algebra of the set of sets. But I can't quite follow your motivations there. What is "$\lvert x\rvert$"? the cardinality of $x$?

Comment: I don't know what you ultimately want to use the probability distribution for, but in any concrete application it should reflect the information you have about the possible sets $x$, which in turn depends on the context where these sets arise. I'll try to give an official answer below with an example.

Comment: Consider this example: there's an urn with $N>5$ balls numbered $1,\dotsc,N$. A person is going to draw a number $n$ (possibly zero) of balls from the urn. You don't know: (1) how many the person will draw, (2) which numbers will be drawn. So the result of this operation is a set of numbered balls. It could be the set $\{\}$, or $\{2\}$, or $\{N\}$, or $\{1,5\}$, or $\{1,\dotsc,N\}$, and so on. You can calculate the probability distribution over this set of sets starting from the multivariate hypergeometric distribution (drawing without replacement) + a distribution for $n$.

Comment: Dear @pglpm, your example considers one RV, e.g. $X$, and it is correct. But, how to perform the computations, e.g., $P(X=\{1,5\}|Y=\{3,4,5\})$ when $X$ and $Y$ are defined like you did? (you are right, $|x|$ is the cardinality of $x$). Excuse me for being quite unclear, all you have helped me a lot in that sense.

Comment: The example only wanted to show that the numerical values of your distribution depend on the meaning of the sets and on the whole situation – but otherwise there isn't anything special in the fact that your unknown quantities are sets.

Comment: Consider this extended example: there is one more urn with $M>5$ numbered balls. One person has drawn $n$ (possibly zero) balls from the first urn and $m$ (possibly zero) balls from the second. You don't know how many balls were drawn, nor their numbers. Donote by $X,Y$ the outcomes of the two draws. The results of the operation could be $X=\{\},Y=\{\}$, or $X=\{\},Y=\{1\}$, or $X=\{\},Y=\{2\}$, and so on up to $X=\{1,\dotsc,N\},Y=\{1,\dotsc, M\}$. You want the joint probability....

Comment: ...You could assume that for each urn the multivariate hypegeometric holds. You need the joint distribution of $n,m$. You might know, for example, that the person always draws the some amounts (because of some superstitious quirk), so $\mathrm{p}(n,m)=\mathrm{p}(n)\delta_{nm}$. Or just consider $\mathrm{p}(n,m)=\text{uniform}$. From this distribution and the hypergeometric ones you can find the joint for $X,Y$ and their conditionals – just using the standard probability rules. (The assumption $\mathrm{p}(n,m)=\text{uniform}$ should lead to independence of the distributions for $X$ and $Y$.)

Comment: I might suggest that you try this example for yourself, with different forms of $\mathrm{p}(n,m)$, and see which results you obtain. I believe this should clarify matters for you more than any abstract explanation.

Comment: @pglpm, my problem is precisely how to implement $\delta_{nm}$, and the options I show in the main question are my attempts to do that, but I don't know if they actually obey standard rules. How to test it? For the moment, these options can be normalized, but I suspect they are not right at all despite of that.

Comment: "How to implement $\delta_{nm}$" – I just meant a Kronecker delta there, $\delta_{nm}=1$ if $n=m$, and $0$ otherwise, so there's nothing to implement really. Have you applied your formulae to a simple, concrete version of your problem where you can do everything by enumeration?

Comment: Thanks @pglpm, I'll try to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Since the expressions for conditional probability involves a sum to marginalise the joint probabilities, you will need to specify the support of the random sets you are dealing with, which will require you to refer to *classes* of sets (i.e., sets of sets).  Thus, the first thing that will be useful here is to use standard fonts for elements, sets, and classes.  For example, you might denote a specific element value by $x$, a set of these values by $\mathcal{X}$, and a class of these sets by $\mathscr{X}$.  Once you are using notation that clearly distinguishes between these things, it is fairly simple to formulate the conditional probability formula for random sets.

For simplicity, I will consider the case where your random sets are discrete random variables (i.e., both have countable support).  Consider the case where we have two random sets $\mathcal{X} \in \mathscr{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y} \in \mathscr{Y}$ where the latter classes are their respective supports.  Then the rule of conditional probability says that:

$$f(\mathcal{Y}| \mathcal{X}) = \frac{f(\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{Y})}{\sum_{\mathcal{Y} \in \mathscr{Y}} f(\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{Y})}.$$

Without specifying how these random sets are constructed from underlying random elements, that is really as far as you can go.  If you are willing to specify how random sets are constructed from some underlying random elements then you might be able to split the term $f(\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{Y})$ into a product of probabilities for those random elements.  At the moment you appear to be trying to split this term out into a sum, but you are trying to do this without giving any information on how the random sets are consructed; consequently, your attempts are all abortive.

Comment: Dear @Ben, I've added information on how the RVs and their possible outcomes are built. This helps you to be more specific in your answer?